# Some misc-type references have commas after URL string while others do not

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing

I am reviewing citations in my thesis, and I noticed something really odd.

[image]

Citation [7] is generated from:

```
@misc{apriori-python,
  title        = {apriori-python},
  howpublished = {\url{https://pypi.org/project/apriori-python/}},
  note         = {Verified: 2021-10-11}
}
```

whereas citation [10] from:

```
@misc{google-colab,
  title        = {Colaboratory},
  howpublished = {\url{https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html}},
  note         = {Verified: 2022-03-24}
}
```

I don't see any differences between both, yet the latter has a comma and a space after the URL string and before the `.` ("period", aka "full stop").

Has anyone stumbled upon a similar problem? What might cause the extra comma to some of my `misc`-type citations?

edit: bib style:

```
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{biblio}
```

Comment: Which bibliography style do you employ?

Comment: @Mico `abbrvnat`

Comment: I'm afraid I am unable to replicate the issue you say you're encountering using just the information you've so far. Specifically, when I try to add some code to make your code snippets minimally compilable, I am unable to generate spurious commas at the ends of URL strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't replicate.

You may provide other informations such as documentclass and packages you used.

Anyway, you can use the following as an alternative solution:

```
@misc{google-colab,
  title        = {Colaboratory},
  note         = {\url{https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html}. Verified: 2022-03-24}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As I already noted in a comment, I am unable to replicate the issue you've encountered.

Anyway, since you employ the `abbrvnat` bibliography style (and load the `natbib` citation management package too, right?), you might as well place the URL strings in a field called `url` instead of in the generic `howpublished` field. Making this switch will also be helpful if you employ the `hyperref` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% create a minimalist bib file 'on the fly':
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{apriori-python,
  title        = {apriori-python},
  url          = {https://pypi.org/project/apriori-python/},
  note         = {Verified: 2021-10-11}
}
@misc{google-colab,
  title        = {Colaboratory},
  url          = {https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html},
  note         = {Verified: 2022-03-24}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{xurl} % allow line breaks anywhere in URL strings
\def\UrlFont{\sffamily} % to mimic font used in screenshot
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % Times Roman clone for text and math

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % optional

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked the class, the extra comma was because I need the year

```
@misc{google-colab,
  title        = {Colaboratory},
  note         = {\url{https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html}.},
  year        = {Verified: 2022-03-24}

}
```

fixed it